# How to save a linux command in a variable to be used in later part of shell-script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I was wondering if we have a provision to do something like this in a shell script:

```
(linux cmd1) > /dev/null 2>&1
b1=$(echo $?)
(linux cmd2) > /dev/null 2>&1
b2=$(echo $?)
if [ $b1 -eq 0 ]; then cmd="cmd1";elif [ $b1 -eq 0 ]; then cmd="cmd2"; else echo "No utility found to check blah blah..."; fi;
```

Basically what I'm trying is to find a way to save the command in a variable `cmd`(like a string), and once when I've figured out which `cmd` to run, I'll then use it (to execute) in later part of my script

Comment: What is the criteria for selecting one of the commands? Wouldn't it be better to check if the command actually exists (like `test -f $(which one_command)`?

Comment: >C='ls -al'; ${C}

Comment: A command *name* is just a string; for anything more complicated, read [Bash FAQ 50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```
cmd="ls -l"
$cmd
result=$?
```